# Stuck on a loop while trying to verify characters from a text file

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have to make a program that reads some "random" strings of letters and numbers from a text file and checking if they meet some conditions that makes them a valid password.

The conditions are: -Have exactly 4 digits
-Have exactly 8 characters
-Have at least one uppercase letter and at least one lowercase letter

The program reads the file and it outputs the number of valid passwords.

This is the format of the text file: 
"eR68G12a  91jY643ebjp eRty74kLh   24fG92  aj85gt32   dGb9357jKoup2 " (on a single line)

The code: 
´´´

```
Program Ej23_version3;

var 
char1,char2:char;
mayus,minus:boolean; // mayus and minus would be uppercase and lowercase respectively
cantDigitos,cantCaracteres,contrasenasValidas:integer;
datos:text;

Begin 
assign(datos,'Datos_guia3_ej23.txt'); reset(datos);
contrasenasValidas := 0;

char1 := ' ';

Read(datos,char2);
while not eof(datos) do 
Begin 
    mayus := false; minus := false; cantDigitos := 0; cantCaracteres := 0;
    if (char1 = ' ') and (char2 <> ' ') then //check if its the beggining of the word
    Begin 
        while not eof(datos) and (char2 <> ' ') do 
        Begin 
            cantCaracteres := cantCaracteres + 1;
            if char2 = UPCASE(char2) then  // if the character2 is equal to the uppercase version of the character2, character2 is uppercase
                mayus := true
            else
                if (char2 in ['0'..'9']) then
                cantDigitos := cantDigitos + 1
                else
                    minus := true;
        if eof(datos) then // when it reaches the end of the file, it also reads and checks the last character
            if char2 = UPCASE(char2) then 
                mayus := true
            else
                if (char2 in ['0'..'9']) then
                cantDigitos := cantDigitos + 1
                else
                    minus := true;
        End;

        if minus and mayus and (cantDigitos = 4) and (cantCaracteres = 8) then //if all conditions are met, the password is valid and its added to the counter
            contrasenasValidas := contrasenasValidas + 1;

        char1 := char2; Read(datos, char2); //char2 should be an empty character by this point, so it passes that value to char1 and reads the next character
    End
End;

WriteLn(contrasenasValidas);
End.
```

But when i run it, it just gets stuck there with only the prompt ticking

Comment: Use the debugger to solve the problem. We are not a replacement for a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you read the file (character by character).

It would be better to read it all at once, and examine all the sequences of eight characters one by one.

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  LFile: TextFile;
  LStr, LSubStr: string;
  LStartIndex: integer;
  LExit: boolean;

begin
  AssignFile(LFile, 'Datos_guia3_ej23.txt');
  Reset(LFile);
  ReadLn(LFile, LStr); // Get the whole line

  LStartIndex := 1; // Search all 8 characters sequences, starting from the first character
  LExit := FALSE;
  repeat
    LSubStr := Copy(LStr, LStartIndex, 8);
    if Length(LSubStr) = 8 then
    begin
      // Here check other conditions
      // ...

      Inc(LStartIndex);
    end else
      LExit := TRUE;
  until LExit;

  CloseFile(LFile);
end.
```